# Android Studio Logcat not showing Dropdown of Verbose, Error and other things

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, logcat

Android Studio is not showing up the dropdown that contains Verbose, Error and other things. I'm following a tutorial and it has that drop down menu, but mine doesn't.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ2Cj.png)

My Android Studio is not having a dropdown containing Verbose, Error and other things like in this image. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qy47.png)

Answer (score 1):

That's the logic from the older Android Studio versions. Now, instead, you can filter logs with keys as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#key-value-search).

In your case, the key is `level`, e.g. `package:mine level:debug`

[image]

Comment: I'm following Unit 1: Kotlin basics of Android Basics in Kotlin course via https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course, and in codelab 6 (Into to debugging) of PATHWAY 4, step 3 refers to Logcat and being able to filter by "select your app (com.example.debugging) from the dropdown menu to filter out any logs that aren't relevant to your app."
Using the above methodology, I was able to find the relevant log (...debugging  V  Hello, world!) here using: package:mine tag:MainActivity in the search box of Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dolphin Android studio then follow these steps :
**Open Setting -> Experimental Tab - > Unchecked Logcat (Enable new Logcat tool window)**